# iPhone 5c can't install Netflix because iOS 11 is required

Tags: iphone, netflix

I have an iPhone 5c and want to download Netflix. Every time I try though, it tells me that I need iOS 11 which my phone can't do. It doesnt give me an option to download the last compatible version. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Can you try from the purchased tab?

Answer (score 3):

- Unless you've bought/downloaded Netflix before (at a time there still was a Netflix app compatible with your current iOS version) you can't access old versions in the store.
- Netflix might have pulled old versions from the store because theAPI between the app and the netflix servers changed and old versions can't talk to the backend any longer